# Binning in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

[image]

I'm new in Dax in PowerBi and I wanna ask you if there is a way in which I can write a function where I can manually group the data in bins for example about `50mm, 25 mm, 10 mm, etc` ?

The intention is to create a filter in which I write the number and then the data will be grouped based onn the values of the specified bins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data doesn't match your bins but regardless, I would do this in Power Query. The absolute easiest way is highlight the column you're binning and then select add column - column from examples on the ribbon. Type in the first bin and Power Query will fill in the rest.

Adjust the bins if required and then click OK.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know here I can find the button to adjust the bins?

Comment: You just overtype the suggested bins (the light grey rows) and it will automatically adjust.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Sadly no, The only solution which I got was to create a column where I group the data manually.

Comment: The instructions are fairly clear. What problem are you facing?

Comment: I have problem by establishing the range. I do everything which you said but when I set the range it does not work for me

Comment: I took screenshots about what I do following your steps.  Maybe I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps which I follow
First

[image]

Second

[image]

Third

[image]

Forth

[image]

Comment: You need to specify the range for the row you're in. i.e. for 3048, you would specify 3000-3049.

Comment: It works but not for direct query, but thank you for your help, I would use import instead of direct query